# JSON to Python dataframe: mapping values from another file

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, api

I have some JSON files like the below, for every student id there will be a corresponding JSON file with mark details.

students.json

```
{
    "Students": [
        {
            "StudentName": "AAA",
            "Sid": 1020,
            "Saddress": "st.aaa",
            "Sdob": "10-11-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "BBB",
            "Sid": 1021,
            "Saddress": "st.bbb",
            "Sdob": "11-11-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "CCC",
            "Sid": 1022,
            "Saddress": "st.fff",
            "Sdob": "05-12-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "DDD",
            "Sid": 1023,
            "Saddress": "st.ddd",
            "Sdob": "15-09-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "EEE",
            "Sid": 1024,
            "Saddress": "st.eee",
            "Sdob": "10-11-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "FFF",
            "Sid": 1025,
            "Saddress": "st.ddd",
            "Sdob": "20-11-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "GGG",
            "Sid": 1026,
            "Saddress": "st.ggg",
            "Sdob": "25-11-1999"
        },
        {
            "StudentName": "JJJ",
            "Sid": 1019,
            "Saddress": "st.aaa",
            "Sdob": "18-11-1999"
        }
    ]
}
```

1020.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1021.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1022.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1023.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1024.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1025.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1026.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

1019.json

```
{
    "marks": [
        {
            "English": 50,
            "Math": 75,
            "Art": 75,
            "Science": 80,
            "History": 30,
            "Geography": 35,
            "Physical Education": 90,
            "Chemistry": 80,
            "Physics": 85,
            "Biology": 75
        }
    ]
}
```

I need to get an output like this
[image: what i need]

My code:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

data_JSON = open("students.json")

json_str = data_JSON.read()
data= json.loads(json_str)

print("JSON Data")
print(data)

def Normalize(data_JSON,record_path):
    temp = json.dumps(data_JSON)
    ar = json.loads(temp)
    df = pd.json_normalize(ar[record_path])
    return df

data2 = Normalize(data, "Students")
print("\nAfter normalizing JSON Data")
print(data2)

df0 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df1 = df0[['StudentName', 'Sid']]
print("\nTaking specific columns from the df")
print(df1)

files = []

for i, row in df1.groupby('Sid').size().iteritems():
    file = str(i)+".json"
    files.append(file)

print("\nFile Names")
print(files)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['StudentName','Sid'])
merged = pd.DataFrame()

for i in files:
    data_JSON = open(i)
    json_str = data_JSON.read()
    data= json.loads(json_str)
    marks = Normalize(data, "marks")
    df = pd.DataFrame(marks)
    merged = pd.concat([df2, df], ignore_index=True, sort=False)

print("\nMarks")
print(merged)

# saving the dataframe
merged.to_csv('StudentsMark.csv',index=False)
```

Output:
[image: output]

is it possible to insert the StudentName and Sid along with the mark? I dont want to give the StudentName and Sid directly to the dataframe df2, when the program fetches the mark from each file it should be able to map and add the StudentName and Sid to df2 for each file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
import json

import pandas as pd


path = "path/to/files"


def get_data(file: str) -> json:
    with open(f"{path}/{file}.json", "r") as f:
        return json.loads(f.read())


students_df = pd.json_normalize(data=get_data("students"), record_path="Students")

student_ids = students_df["Sid"].tolist()
grades_df = pd.concat([pd.json_normalize(data=get_data(x), record_path="marks").assign(Id=x) for x in student_ids])

(pd
 .merge(left=students_df, right=grades_df, left_on="Sid", right_on="Id")
 .drop(columns="Id")
 .to_csv(f"{path}/students_marks.csv", index=False)
 )
```

Comment: Hi @JasonBaker, instead of the same mark for every subject I tried with **different marks for each subject** . for example `1019.json` I gave marks as `"English": 1, "Math": 2, "Art": 3, "Science": 4, "History": 5, "Geography": 6, "Physical Education": 7, "Chemistry": 8, "Physics": 9, "Biology": 10` . likewise, the other json files will contain different marks/values. but in the output CSV file, I got the same mark for every subject. can u help me here?

Comment: I just changed the marks and it worked as expected. Perhaps you have a typo?

Comment: hi @JasonBaker, I have posted a similar question in another thread [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75573060/json-to-python-dataframe-mapping-values-from-another-api), can you use the same logic in there? instead of offline files, I'm using the data directly from the API